# Почему не работает count в Mysql

Tags: mysql

Делаю запрос вида

```
SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE TRUE AND year = 2013 AND market_id = 1
```

Почему-то возвращает ноль, не могу понять почему?
Делаю по отдельности

```
SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE TRUE AND year = 2013
```

Все считает, пробую с market_id, тоже считает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот запись, которая соответствует критерию. И их очень много
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал вот такой запрос

```
SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE TRUE AND year = 2013 AND publisher = 'Феникс' AND market_id = 1
```

Ответ выдал 657

Comment: строку покажи где `year = 2013 AND market_id = 1`

Comment: Не совсем понял, что показать?

Comment: Такую запись из твоей таблицы где `year = 2013 AND market_id = 1`

Comment: ну значит нет такой записи.

Comment: Есть и их очень много.

Comment: Могу таблицу скинуть у меня и показать что запрос работает.

Comment: запрос где делаешь? в PHP? или phpmyadmin? попробуй в консоли запрос сделать

Comment: В админире. Не могу понять, почему он не работает

Comment: То есть он работает, но возвращает ноль записей

Comment: @shatoidil а ты уверен что там у тебя нечего другого не поставляеться в запросе?

Comment: попробуй в консоли запрос сделать...... возможно кэш

Comment: Дописал инфу в вопрос, попробывал другой запрос, выдал нормальный ответ.

Comment: @shatoidil перезагрузи сервер, `apache` и `mysql` и попробуй с ново.

Comment: Про кэширование запросов: https://habrahabr.ru/post/41166/

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan Перезагрузил сервер и все за работало) Можете вписать в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `mysql` есть кэширование запросов, можно прочитать [тут](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Query_Cache_How.html).

Перезагрузите сервис `mysql`. Это видно потому что Эти две запросы один имеет результат другой нет, но их результаты вложенные

**Нулевой результат**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE TRUE AND year = 2013 AND market_id = 1
```

**Есть результат**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE TRUE AND year = 2013 AND publisher = 'Феникс' AND market_id = 1
```

И второй вложен в первый.